# Angular not detecting changes

Tags: angular, visual-studio

Few days back i stated learning angular. I am following some course. I am building an app with help of that course.

When started that course, i was using **linux** as Operating system. It was working fine. I pushed all the code to github.

But then...

I installed windows 10 on the same system.

On windows, i have c#, visual studio 2019 also installed. So, **When i run the project on visual studio, i
runs fine....but even if i make a slightest change , angular is not detecting that.**

P.S. => I installed typescript, node , angular-cli on windows.

```
C:\Users\M\source\repos\AngularApp>ng serve -o
Your global Angular CLI version (9.1.4) is greater than your local
version (9.1.3). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 26.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 141 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 849 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.02 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-05-11T07:02:42.689Z - Hash: 387922666fdbb3733970 - Time: 6407ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
: Compiled successfully.
```

This is what i get, after i run `ng serve` 
i am really confused, i am not getting what went wrong.

Comment: Try updating your local angular cli version same as the global one.

Comment: when you change , do you mean in `html` and `ts` files? Does it work when you do "hard reload and clear cache" using refresh button

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using `node_modules` installed by linux. Try to remove the `node_modules` folder and reinstall the modules with `npm install`.